# Cómo enviar html por correo y este se lea

Tags: html, css

Quiero enviar una pequeña pagina en `html` pero al correo me llega solo el codigo y quiero que me llegue ya la página, así como hacen los correos promocionales.

```
<textarea>
 <div class="pag">
  <h1>Promociones</h1>
    <div class="item"><h2>Product 1</h2><button>Ver</button></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Product 2</h2><button>Ver</button></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>Product 3</h2><button>Ver</button></div>
 </div>
</textarea>

<style>
.pag {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-beetwen;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: ¿Qué usas para enviar los correos? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: El formulario de contacto

Comment: No, me refiero a si usas la función `mail` de PHP o bibliotecas como `PHPMailer`. Comparte el código PHP con el que intentas enviar el correo.

Comment: agrega el codigo PHP con el que envias el correo, para poder darte una mejor solución

Comment: No sé sí sepas, pero si quieres enviar una maquetación a un correo electrónico ten en cuenta que todo eso se hace con tablas, sí no sale sin diseño; tendrías que hacerlo con tablas como se hacía antiguamente en en FrontEnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial).

Dentro de tutorial `PHPMailer` da un ejemplo de como hacerlo de manera simple:

```
<?php
equire 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject = 'An HTML Message';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'Hello, <b>my friend</b>! This message uses HTML!'; // codigo html
```

Lo que yo hice fue lo siguiente:

```
<?php
// ... 
$mail->Body = "
<html>
<body>
<h1 style='color: #c295f6;'>Gracias</h1>
<p>
 Gracias por estar otro año con nosotros...
</p>
mas codigo html
</body>
</html>
";
?>
```

Lo actualice un poco porque fue un mensaje enviado para año nuevo en 2018. Pero como puedes ver, dentro de `html` tambien utilice `css` y el correo se ve bien y elegante.

`PHPMailer` es una herramienta muy buena para enviar este tipo de mensaje y a la vez muy segura.

Espero te servida!